# drush sql-dump skip extended inserts?

Tags: drush

Does drush have an option in its `sql-dump` command to skip extended inserts?

I am looking for a particular value in the database, and having shorter lines would be a boon for my task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it has, just add `--ordered-dump` parameter to the `sql-dump` command, e.g.

```
drush sql-dump --ordered-dump
```

Tested under Drush 8.x.